# How to iterate through multiple data frames in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, loops, correlation

I've created a dict that appears to consist of multiple data frames parsed by location.  However, when I try to iterate through the dict to run correlations by location, it appears as if it's running a correlation on the entire set.

I have split the data frame by locations (Store_ID), and the loop will print each Store_ID but because the correlations are exactly the same in each iteration, I suspect it's just using the entire dataset and not iterating through data frame in the dict.

I started with:

```
stores = df.Store_ID.unique()

storedict = {elem : pd.DataFrame() for elem in stores}

for key in storedict.keys():
    storedict[key] = df[:][df.Store_ID == key]
```

`np.array(storedict)` prints the array, grouped by each location.

But this loop (below), though it iterates through stores when it prints, seems to return the same correlation coefficients as though it's just repeating the Pearson correlation on the entire set of locations (stores).

What I'm trying to do is have it show, e.g. the Store ID and the correlation matrix for the data associated with that Store ID, then the next Store ID and its correlation matrix, and so on...

I must be missing something idiotically obvious here.  What is it?

EDIT:

So when I run:

```
for store in stores:
    print("\r")
    print(store)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 100)
    pd.set_option('precision', 3)
    correlations = data.corr(method='pearson')
    print(correlations)
```

I get the same list of correlations.  I wonder if it's because `data` is defined globally as:

```
data = df.drop(['datestring'], axis=1)
data.index = df.datestring
values = data.values
```

I think `data.corr` is ignoring the tuple and looking at the original dataframe. How do I define correlations so that it runs iteratively for "data" from each store, not all stores?  Again here what I wanted to do was iteratively split the one data frame into many and run correlation on each store as a separate data frame (or however else is easiest to get it to work without multiplying the volume of code to tackle something that could be looped.

Comment: You can create your dict with `dict(tuple(df.groupby('Store_ID')))`. Perhaps the error is with your chained indexing `][`

Comment: Could you provide some input data?!

Comment: ALollz: Thanks! I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @ALollz see edit in post... that didn't quite work... unless it is working and every store's data in this example just happens to be correlated the same.